# Elasticsearch completion suggestion case insensitive

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm doing an auto-complete in java using elasticsearch, so for that I built and map with the following code:

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {            
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
     "product": {  
        "properties": {
           "product_suggestions" : {
              "type" :            "completion",
              "index_analyzer" :  "whitespace_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer" : "whitespace_analyzer",

              "preserve_position_increments": false,
              "preserve_separators": false
            }

        }
     }      
   }
}
```

And put the following index:

```
{
    "product_suggestions" : {"input":["Apple II Lisa","Apple"]}
}
```

and

```
{    
    "product_suggestions" : {"input":["Iphone 5s","apple"]}
}
```

If in java I do:

```
SuggestRequestBuilder req = esClient.prepareSuggest("auction").addSuggestion(
        new CompletionSuggestionFuzzyBuilder("searchSuggestion").field("product_suggestions").text(query).size(10));

SuggestResponse suggestResponse = req.execute().actionGet();
```

With the query "app" I will get "apple","Apple" and "Apple II Lisa".

Someone knows how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Getting apple and Apple (should receive only Apple and Apple II Lisa)

Comment: your question is too confusing.. pls provide an example expectation. and let us help u..!

Comment: With the word app the possibilities are "Apple", "Apple II Lisa" and "apple" (lets say the order is this one), so what I'm expecting to see in the suggestion box is Apple and "Apple II Lisa" because the word apple is the same as one that is already in the result (without capitalized A). I don't know if is this possible to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just followed in other path... set lowercase all words before indexing and this way the elasticsearch will only output apple and "apple ii lisa" (the ones of my example). I notice that is what google does also!! This will also avoid more complicated operations and maybe speedup my app!!

Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: would be good if you could add the java code for creating the XContentBuilder object creation, esp. the analyser portion