# How to limit elastic suggestion with complex conditions?

Tags: elasticsearch

Limiting elastic query is not complicated, for example:

```
`  "query":{
    "bool":{ 
      "must":[
        {"terms":{"brand":["micromax","samsung"]}},
        {
        "bool":{
          "should":[
            { "range": { "price": { "gte": 6000, "lte": 10000 } } },
            { "range": { "price": { "gte": 16000, "lte": 30000 } } }
            ] 
        }
        } 
      ] 
    }
  }`
```

But how can limit elastic suggestion with complex conditions (a condition with 'match', 'must', 'should', 'not',... on different fields)?

Is it possible to set a complex condition in 'collate'?

Comment: What your scenary for complex condition? describe better your doubt.

Comment: I can limit my 'elastic query' with multiple 'should, match,... keywords'. so my question is how can i do same thing in 'elastic suggestion'?

Comment: so you have a suggestion query (autocomplete) and you want to apply filters to restrict the results, right? Do you have the query? Can you provide documents for testing and say what result you expect?

Comment: that's right. I just need a simple example with some conditions applied. It doesn't matter what the query is.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690001/elasticsearch-completion-suggestion-case-insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow what the [post](https://medium.com/@mourjo_sen/a-detailed-comparison-between-autocompletion-strategies-in-elasticsearch-66cb9e9c62c4) says you can create an index and make your suggestion with aggregation. Note that I used an analyzer and the aggs is in the keyword type field.
In this example, you search for "micr" and receive the suggestion "micromax". If you change the price, the suggestion will not return results if the price is greater than 10.
That way you can apply restriction rules (the way you want) in your suggestion.

Mapping

```
PUT index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "brand": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
          },
          "raw_term": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data

```
POST index/_doc
{
 "brand":"micromax",
 "price":10
}


POST index/_doc
{
 "brand":"samsung",
 "price":10
}
```

Query

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 10,
              "lte": 20
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "brand.autocomplete": "micr"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "suggestion": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand.raw_term",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
 "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "suggestion": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "micromax",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```